# jquery theme for phpbb?

Tags: jquery, themes, phpbb

Is there any possible way to apply jquery theme (theme roller) to PHPBB forums?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the jQuery.ui theme, it's possible but would require a whole theme using jQuery.ui. That would take a while to make! Have you looked around at other options themewise?